# How to modularize a javascript function which uses constructor.prototype?

Tags: javascript, jquery, constructor, prototype, modularity

## Modularization

I am working on a simple javascript library which works like jQuery, but I want to add more features to it.

The code is starting to get big (~300 lines) and I want to modularize it. The basic structure is this:

```js
var $ = function(){
   constructor = function(selector){
      //query selector all the elements with selector
}

var instantiate = function(selector){
   return new constructor(selector)
}

return instantiate;

}()
```

And features work like this:

```js
constructor.prototype.someFunction = function(){
    //do something
}
```

So, I wonder: what is the best way to modularize it? Do I just create separated files with functions and then call it in constructor.prototype? Do I import this function and modify it in other files?

I do not mind changing the whole code if it is necessary or makes a good improvement.

Comment: For one thing: `constructor.prototype = {fn1: function(){}, fn2: function(){}, /*...*/}`

Comment: The `constructor(selector){` line is a syntax error, looks like it's missing a `function` keyword?

Comment: Is `$` really a factory function for `instantiate`s, or is that an IIEFE?

Comment: It is not missing a function keyword in the code. I just forgot to put it here. I am editing it now

Comment: That's what I thought, thanks. (Should be either `function constructor(selector) {` or `var constructor = function(selector) {` though)

Comment: Are you planning to use ES6 modules? Or just multiple script files? Are you going to do any bundling/concatenation?

Comment: Bergi, I am planing on using es6 modules

Comment: In that case, start by dropping the IIFE and just `default export function instantiate(…) { … }`. Yes, you would import function from other files and call them, or install them as methods directly. No, you would not import the prototype object elsewhere to modify it.